# PHP -- using session variables / reloading the page (logging in/out)

Tags: php

I am building a login system and have a mysql query that checks the name and password and puts out a page saying 'logged' if they match.

what I want to know is how i can use session variables to see if the user is logged in and then redirect them to a different page if they are.

do i have to set all session varaibles in the same php code snippet as the 'session_start();'
or can i do some like this on the same page

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

html here

<?php $_SESSION['test'] = blah; ?>
```

if i call it another page do i have to have the session_start(); there too?  or can i just $_REQUEST any session variable from any page one the session starts?

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `session_start()` **once** in each script that need to use sessions. After you called it you can read variables that were set in another script calls and set new ones.

Comment: so everytime a session variable is called or set, i have to put session_start() in the script its called in, correct?  also, can i use $_REQUEST?

Comment: @Shawn: `session_start` need to be called once per request. And it is better to use $_SESSION

Comment: @Shawn: "request" is one "page request" in your browser. A process between you entered an url and got complete page. Doesn't matter how many scripts were included/required there, you need to `session_start` just once and before you need to access/write data to $_SESSION at the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call session_start() on all your pages that need to use $_SESSION . The best way is to include it once for all on a header or config php file at the top of all your pages.

You don't need to SESSION all your vars. It is not safe to trust them. Best is to store user_id/username and password, and re-check them on the top of your pages.

Comment: Why is it not safe to trust session data? And believe me, to store username and re-check on each page is not the "best", but silly advice.

Comment: okay, some conflicting info here. . do i have to call the function start_session every script or just once a page?

Comment: @Shawn: it is better to say "once per request". Not per each included php file.

Comment: I think a simple and universal rule is "never trust data that could be modified by user". Especially sessions/cookies. I've always stored a session_id in my $_SESSION var and then re-check it on my pages. Sorry for my use of "Best" cauz of course there is no "Best practice" usage. That's just what I do. Why do you think this is silly?

Comment: @CoBaLt2760: it is silly because **session data cannot be modified by user**

Comment: so everytime i set or call a $_SESSION i need to call that function is that what you're saying?

Comment: okay okay. I just feel strange to rely on data entered once without no further tests.. And according to me, security can suffers a simple check in DB for the SESSION id/hash_pass stored. But ok, my way ;)

Comment: @Shawn : to retrieve $_SESSION data, you need to have called once session_start(). In many of my apps, I use SESSION vars on a lot of pages. That's why I personally always call session_start() in my header.php included page. Careful, you need to call this function before every output text! If you make an echo, print before this call, sesssions won't work

Comment: cobalt can you elaborate on that last sentence.. you said once per page, and then you say before every output text

Comment: okay. Sorry for my poor english :( You have to call it once per page needing to use a $_SESSION var, but to call it very early in your code, at the top, before any output. eg: <?php session_start(); blablablabla $_SESSION['myvar']; balalala ?>

Comment: i see, thank you. i'm just wondering that .. can the session_start be in another php script than the one its originally called in?  <?php session_start(); blablablabla?>  <?php $_SESSION['myvar']; balalala ?>

Comment: Yes, absolutely. For example for me, I have session_start() called in my header.php witch is included by all my pages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call session_start in every page which you need to check $_SESSION which iw virtually every page in a script which requires higher privileges. Eg logins

Make sure the call is once.
Included files can have session start as well and this will throw an error. You can perform a simple check before starting a session in an included file by checking if $_SESSION is set before calling session_start.

Best practice is to check the session at the top of the page before any other processing and also to ensure That you do it before any data is sent to the browser. Eg through echo, or whitespace before

Though all data is usually unsafe, (basically user data) sessions are safer than the post or get or cookie or simply request and some server variables since you set it yourself. That is unless it is hijacked. Read on session hijacking as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can include only one common file and add session_start(); in that file and in that also you can check if user_name or password is set then redirect. like this

```
if(session_id()){
   session_start();
}
```

then check

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){
    // redirect here to the login page or any page you want
}
```

You will need to check if login is correct and then set $_SESSION['user_name'] so that manage session afterwards